# Create Both Parent/Child Associated Record in Sailsjs

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out if sails/waterline even does this.
(so an adequate answer would simply be if this is possible or not, I have been reading docs, looking through github issues and looking through code, but still not sure)

I have a one to one association setup where an 'account' has a 'contact'

I'm trying to create a contact within sails blueprints (so basically just using the create() method)

```
account = 
{ name: 'Corp'
     contact:{
       firstName: 'Bob',
       lastName: 'Jones'
     }
}
```

so should Account.create(account).exec() create the account and the associated contact? Because I'm getting the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot convert null to object
```

My model is setup like so

```
account.js
module.exports = {
  migrate: 'safe',
  tableName: 'accounts',
  autoPK: false,
  attributes: {
        id: {
                type: 'INTEGER', 
                primaryKey: true,
                autoIncrement: true
            },
        contactId: 'INTEGER',
        name: {type: 'STRING', maxLength: 100},

        contact: {
            model: 'contact',
            columnName:'contactId'
        }

    }
};
```

I'm using sails 10.0-rc8 / waterline 10.0-rc15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I found out that as of version 0.10.0-rc15 of waterline you can NOT have a customized foreign keys. In the above model if I change the "contactId" column to just "contact" (basically make it look exactly like it does in the docs. Then it works.

I made the following bug report
https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/529

Comment: FYI: In current versions this is now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Creating an associated instance at the same time as its parent (aka "nested create") should work, but it's tricky to get things just right when you're dealing with a legacy database.  In your case, the `contactId` attribute declaration is probably causing the issue, since Waterline expects the foreign key field to be implicit, not explicit.  Try removing:

```
contactId: 'INTEGER',
```

entirely and see where that gets you.

Comment: No where, same error message. I feel like legacy DBs are more trouble than sails is worth. Sails really, really wants to build the DB for me.

Comment: I just ran a new test with letting sails create my DB for me and it still does not work. Same error message.

Comment: Hm, odd indeed.  I'd check that everything is installed properly by doing a minimum test, just `attributes: {name: 'string', contact: {model: 'contact'}}`; if that doesn't work, then there's some other underlying problem...

Comment: Ya, I'm going to try my hand at a completely dry app and see what happens.

Comment: looking at github issues it seems as if you mess with the primary key it does not work in sails.